# RStudio unable to detect or Display Git in Environment quadrant

Tags: git, rstudio

I have just installed Git, R and RStudio to my Windows PC, however, RStudio is unable to detect Git, despite following setup instructions exactly. I've installed the latest 64bit version 2023.03.0 Build 386 to Windows 10 Pro.

Just wondering what steps I might take to resolve this. I've reviewed other related questions to this here but nothing is addressing this issue. Thanks.

Followed installation instructions, generated and applied an RSA key, copied it to GitHub, but just now when reopening RStudio, I notice the SSH key has defaulted to an ED25519 key, not the original RSA key I generated. I'm wondering if this is the issue somewhere.

[image]